# How to monitor Java Heroku application dyno usage?

Tags: java, heroku, scalability, monitoring, paas

I would like to know if it is possible to know web dyno usage in **heroku**?

For example, I would like to know if my dyno is using 100% of its resources, or it is just idling, so I could add or remove more dynos in order to have optimal resource utilization.

Heroku command line client gives only information about number of dynos and **uptime**, without further details.
Something like dyno equivalent of **cpu usage**, **requests per sec per dyno** or **average response time** of actual requests would be helpful.

I know there are some addons that work with Ruby, but I'm interested in ways to monitor **Java / Clojure** application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to get this kind of information on Heroku is with the [New Relic](http://addons.heroku.com/newrelic) add-on.  It does work with Java but I'm not sure there is any specific Java on Heroku + New Relic documentation yet.